# error: cannot find symbol 'MENU_SELECTION_MANAGER_LISTENER_KEY'

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-7, src, rt.jar

I compile jdk source codes (`jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz`) and encounter the following error.

```
jdk_src/javax/swing/MenuSelectionManager.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
                Object o = context.get(SwingUtilities2.MENU_SELECTION_MANAGER_LISTENER_KEY);
                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable MENU_SELECTION_MANAGER_LISTENER_KEY
  location: class SwingUtilities2
```

There is no `SwingUtilities2.java` at all in `src.zip` and nowhere to define `MENU_SELECTION_MANAGER_LISTENER_KEY`. How to fix it?